# How to avoid overwriting AndroidManifest.xml in Cordova Android application?

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I am creating an application using Cordova. In the platforms folder there is an AndroidManifest.xml file where we can specify the version and other things. But whenever I run the app using `cordova run android` it reinitializes the file and makes it to the previous state as it was before editing and specifying version name.

Does anyone knows how to stop replacing that file while running that command?

Comment: Never edit the AndroidManifest.xml manually, you can edit a lot of the values from the config.xml and for some others you will have to use a plugin or a hook

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the sdk versions in your **config.xml**, as it is the source for generating the AndroidManifest. Your can add the sdk versions in your config.xml like this:

```
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20" />
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting.. But I don't want to change the sdk version, I need to change the application version like 1.0.1. After changing the version and theme of that application and running `cordova run android` command it is reverting whatever changes I have made.

Comment: Sorry i missunterstood your question then^^ Try editing the version attribute of the widget-tag in your config.xml like: `<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myapp66a535" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">`